# How to handle access tokens and API calls with Auth0 SDK?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, access-token, auth0

I am using Auth0 for my authentication and what i understand so far is that i need to get the access token every time i want to make a call to my API with the **getAccessTokenSilently()** method and then put it in the Authorization Header. I want to know if i should store the access token after the user logs in and what is the most secure place to store it?
Is it a good idea to store it in a cookie or in a React Context object?

So far i have read most of the Auth0 documentation but there are too many implementations and i can't understand how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, these access tokens must be retrieved instantly from Auth0 server before every API call.

Access tokens varies based on the audience (the external api resource name).

We should not store this token into browser session or cookie. Even if we store access token has expiry date, so API call with expired token will fail.

Usually Custom API token has default life time of 24 hours.
Special type of user info API token has fixed time of 2 hours after that it will expire